# Javascript event listener fails because "undefined" is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener

I've been working with this for a few hours and it's driving me mad. I've got a modal window that pops up on click of a link. It's got a CSS transition so it fades in. I need to have a callback for when that transition completes. So I dug up this event listener:

```
$('#tagBox').addEventListener(
    'webkitTransitionEnd', 
    function(event) { 
        alert( "Finished transition!" ); }, 
    false );
```

I'm in Safari, but that code returns this error:

`TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('#tagBox').addEventListener( 'webkitTransitionEnd', function(){ alert( "Finished transition!" ) }, false )')`

Is my syntax correct? I can do `alert($('#tagBox'))` and it returns [object] so it's finding the modal element. Why does it say undefined is not a function?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use `bind` instead?

Comment: That'll repeat over and over, right?

Comment: Only when the eventType has been triggered…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something should like to be:

```
$('#tagBox').bind('webkitTransitionEnd', function() {
   //....
});
```

And if you want to fire just once, you could use [.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/):

```
$('#tagBox').one('webkitTransitionEnd', function() {
   //....
});
```

Comment: This repeats over and over, how can I have it just happen on complete

Comment: The event is fired when transition ends, what do you mean by "repeats over and over"?

Comment: Sorry, I have a bunch of transitions going on within #tagbox. Fixed by doing $(this).unbind() inside that bind event.

Comment: @JacksonGariety You could use `.one` for that.

Comment: How can I combine them so It works in opera and firefox as well? How do I add in the oTransitionEnd?

Answer (score 6):

$('#tagBox') returns a jQuery element which doesn't have addEventListener method which is a native method. You need to get the raw DOM before calling addEventListener by doing:

```
$('#tagBox')[0].addEventListener(// your code
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing the event parameter?

```
box.addEventListener( 
'webkitTransitionEnd', 
function( event ) { 
     alert( "Finished transition!" ); 
}, false );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the most recent version of jquery 1.7+ you'll actually be looking for "on"
http://api.jquery.com/on/ which will allow you to add your events to it.

```
$('#tagBox').on('webkitTransitionEnd', function(event) { alert('whatever'); });
```

---

Combined with [jQuery off](http://api.jquery.com/off/):

```
$('#tagBox').on('webkitTransitionEnd', function(event) { 
    $('#tagBox').off('webkitTransitionEnd');
    alert('whatever'); 
});
```

Comment: That is looping over and over and over. I want tit to just happen once.